# Pytest: KeyError: WindowsPath('D:/Local_Project_Directory/Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/testing/conftest.py')

Tags: python, pytest

I'm new to Pytest and developing in general.. I am trying to run a simple pytest assertion, however am getting the error:

```
KeyError: WindowsPath('D:/ireact-tester-if/Lib/site-packages/matplotlib/testing/conftest.py')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:383: in visit
    for x in Visitor(fil, rec, ignore, bf, sort).gen(self):
lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:435: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:435: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:435: in gen
    for p in self.gen(subdir):
lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:424: in gen
    dirs = self.optsort([p for p in entries
lib\site-packages\py\_path\common.py:425: in <listcomp>
    if p.check(dir=1) and (rec is None or rec(p))])
lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py:626: in _recurse
    ihook = self.gethookproxy(dirpath)
lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py:445: in gethookproxy
    my_conftestmodules = pm._getconftestmodules(fspath)
lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:437: in _getconftestmodules
    mod = self._importconftest(conftestpath)
lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:484: in _importconftest
    self.consider_conftest(mod)
lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:537: in consider_conftest
    self.register(conftestmodule, name=conftestmodule.__file__)
lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py:343: in register
    ret = super().register(plugin, name)
lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:127: in register
    hook._maybe_apply_history(hookimpl)
lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py:333: in _maybe_apply_history
    res = self._hookexec(self, [method], kwargs)
lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:93: in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:87: in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\testing\conftest.py:10: in pytest_configure
    matplotlib._init_tests()
Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py:1361: in _init_tests
    faulthandler.enable()
E   AttributeError: 'LogFile' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

The pytest script I am trying to run is simply:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def nominal():
    x=1
    y=2
    yield x, y

def test_one(nominal):
    assert nominal[1] > nominal[0]
```

I am using pyenv with python 3.6.8, I have pytest and all its associated libraries installed. I have no idea why this is happening. Does anyone have any clues on how to solve this?

Comment: Try moving your test script to a different directory.

Comment: Hey Mike, I tried moving the test script to another directory, however this didn't work. What did work was changing directory in the command prompt to the folder where the test script is and by running pytest was successful. However, this does not solve the problem. I need pytest to be able to run from the root folder, seeing that there will be multiple test scripts in different locations of the project.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple test directories pytest will use:

```
pytest <my_test_directory1> <my_test_directory2> <my_test_directory3>
```

Replace `<my_test_directory1>` with the first directory and `<my_test_directory2>` with the second directory that contain your tests.